# Renaming Labels within a column in R

Tags: r, rename

I have a column in my R data which is a question where people had 5 possible answers to choose from, the choices are really long and I'm trying to rename them so that they're shorter.

For example, the original value *"No difficulties with day-to-day activities.
For example: Your Parkinson's disease at present is not affecting your daily living."* should become *"No_Difficulties"*.

I've tried a whole heap of functions e.g.

```
`Filtered_MIandP_Survey$Q11<-recode(Filtered_MIandP_Survey$Q11,'No difficulties with day-to-day activities. For example: Your Parkinson's disease at present is not affecting your daily living.'= 'No_Difficulty')
```

BUT the apostrophe in the word Parkinson's is messing up R and when I change it so there is speech marks around the original phrase it says it's worked but there is no change in the data set.

Comment: If you use ```dplyr```, then putting your data in a pipe and using ```case_when``` could be a great solution for something like this. i.e. ```df%>%mutate(Q11 = case_when(grepl("Your Parkinson's disease at present is not affecting your daily living", Q11) ~ "No_Difficulties",
                            grepl("Your Parkinson's disease at present is somewhat affecting your daily living", Q11) ~ "Some_Difficulties")```

Comment: Thanks for replying :) - I tried the code and it doesn't bring up any errors - it brings up a tibble of the data but doesn't change any of the data point in the column Q11. Honestly, it's such a simple thing and it's driving me crazy so I really appreciate you messaging back

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option using `dplyr`:

```
data %>% rename("new_column" = "old_column")
```

In this case, this would be:

```
data %>% rename("No_Difficulties" = "No difficulties with day-to-day activities. For example: Your Parkinson's disease at present is not affecting your daily living.")
```

Comment: Doesn't that option just rename column titles though? I am trying to rename data within the column so it isn't so long

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really change much from my comment, but I thought I'd share it in an answer since it's easier to show outputs and steps to see what the discrepancy is in the code!

```
library(dplyr)

Filtered_MIandP_Survey<-data.frame("Q11" = c("Your Parkinson's disease at present is not affecting your daily living",
                         "Your Parkinson's disease at present is somewhat affecting your daily living"))

Filtered_MIandP_Survey
                                                                          Q11
1      Your Parkinson's disease at present is not affecting your daily living
2 Your Parkinson's disease at present is somewhat affecting your daily living

Filtered_MIandP_Survey%>%
  mutate(Q11 = case_when(grepl("Your Parkinson's disease at present is not affecting your daily living", Q11) ~ "No_Difficulties",                             
                         grepl("Your Parkinson's disease at present is somewhat affecting your daily living", Q11) ~ "Some_Difficulties"))

                Q11
1   No_Difficulties
2 Some_Difficulties
```

So I made the fake dataframe, matching the name you had, showing two examples of `Q11`. Then I use use mutate with case_when to find those instances, and change it if it matches. I know you said this didn't work in the comment, maybe I had something off there, does this work for you?

Comment: I really appreciate trying again for me - I don't know what it's doing but it still just comes up with a tibble of the data in the R console and doesn't change any of the data values so its not coming up with any errors but it's not changing anything either. I might just go back to qualtrics and try to export it giving assigned numbers instead of the full answer - see if that will work because it might be easier to change?

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you run the code I present, does that at least work correctly, even if not applied to your data? If it doesn't work for you, maybe a package or something is out of date. If my code works for you, then I would imagine it's something in your data that is unusual. If that's the case, would you be able to provide a small subset of your data to test? i.e. ```dput(head(Filtered_MIandP_Survey, 5))```. This would give us 5 lines to test. Obviously we'd only need relevant columns that represent the issue, so even if it's just the ```Q11``` column, that would be great.